# Limit the number of threads in an iteration ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

When I have my code like this, I get "can't create thread, resource temporarily unavailable".  There are over 24k files in the directory to process.

```
frames.each do |image|
    Thread.new do
        pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.
            source(File.open("original/#{image}"))
            .append("-fuzz", "30%")
            .append("-transparent", "#ff00fe")
        result = pipeline.call

        puts result.path
        file_parts = image.split("_")
        frame_number = file_parts[2]
        FileUtils.cp(result.path, "transparent/image_transparent_#{frame_number}")

        puts "Done with #{image}!"
        puts "#{Dir.children("transparent").count.to_s} / #{Dir.children("original").count.to_s}"
        puts "\n"   
    end
end.each{ |thread| thread.join }
```

So, I tried the first 1001 files by calling the index 0-1000, and did it this way:

```
frames[0..1000].each_with_index do |image, index|
    thread = Thread.new do
        pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.
            source(File.open("original/#{image}"))
            .append("-fuzz", "30%")
            .append("-transparent", "#ff00fe")
        result = pipeline.call

        puts result.path
        file_parts = image.split("_")
        frame_number = file_parts[2]
        FileUtils.cp(result.path, "transparent/image_transparent_#{frame_number}")

        puts "Done with #{image}!"
        puts "#{Dir.children("transparent").count.to_s} / #{Dir.children("original").count.to_s}"
        puts "\n"   
    end
    thread.join
end
```

And while this is processing, the speed seems to be about the same as if it was on a single thread when I'm watching it in the Terminal.

But I want the code to be able to limit to whatever the OS will allow before it disallows, so that it can parse through them all faster.

Or at lease:

1. Find the maximum threads allowed
2. Get original directory's count, divided by the number of threads allowed.
3. Run this each in batches of that division.

Comment: This sounds like a good application for a [`Thread::Queue`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Thread/Queue.html) – put all the frames into a queue, then use a bunch of worker threads to process the items. You could even use multiple queues to separate the processing steps.

Comment: BTW, the optimum number of threads depends on many factors like CPU, memory, disk I/O. For CPU heavy tasks, it's usually equal to the number of cores you have. Task with a lot of I/O can utilize more threads, but at some point, adding more threads won't reduce the total time. I would be surprised if anything above 100 threads has significant impact.

Comment: There is not much sense in attempts to maximize the treads number up to the system limits - after some number of threads (way below the system's maximum) performance will start to degrade due to the context switching costs. Theoretically it is possible to calculate the optimum for each particular case, but I doubt it worth the efforts. Thread pool of a reasonable size is all what you need (for example you could go with Brian Goetz's heuristic `Number of threads = Number of Available Cores * (1 + Wait time / Service time)` /"Java Concurrency in Practice"/)

Comment: Which Ruby engine? And why? This seems like: 1) a premature optimization, since it's unclear what sort of real-world gain this would give you, and 2) there are all sorts of things that impact threading and performance in general, including system architecture, cores, Ruby VM, the impact of the GVL if your engine uses it, and so on. IMHO eventing or threading are useful primarily for managing I/O delays, not for "making things faster," so you need to define your objective before it makes sense to answer what may be an X/Y problem.

Comment: standard ruby 3.1.  Parsing through 24k+ image files using ImageMagick and applying the -fuzz and -transparent flags to the file (processing chroma key).  Allowing this to be done sequentially would take a very long time.  So wanted it to at least process it in smaller batches across several threads.

Comment: @PatrickVellia It's likely that you need *parallel* execution, not multi-threaded concurrency. Threads generally solve for a different problem. What you really want to do is run more processes on more cores, so you likely either need to change your Ruby engine, use a parallel execution library, or distribute the workload across multiple nodes.